# Is there a using namespace equivalent pre-version 5?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In PowerShell version 5 they introduced the `using` keyword which I can use to shorten namespace references.

```
Using namespace "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices"
$objExchange = New-Object Data.ExchangeService([Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010)
```

as opposed to

```
$objExchange = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)
```

The savings from this can be great when used multiple times. My issue is that some of my scripts still need to be run in PowerShell v2 environments where this is not supported.

Is there a PowerShell v2 equivalent to this behavior? The closest thing I have been able to find is a module set that [scrubs scriptblocks and manually adds the "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices" behind the scenes](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/04/27/a-day-in-the-life-of-a-poshoholic-creating-and-using-type-accelerators-and-namespaces-the-easy-way/). Not exactly what I was going for.

> ```
>  # Use the Windows.Forms namespace
>  Use-Namespace -Namespace Windows.Forms -ScriptBlock {
>     [DialogResult]$result = [MessageBox]::Show(‘Test’)
>  }
> ```